# When using the dock on bottom of screen with auto-hide enabled, right-click selection menus will jump down when I click. How can I stop this behavior?

Tags: 22.04, dock

I've screengrabbed a quick GIF of what I'm talking about here:

[image: GIF screencap]

I attempt to close Steam with a right-click and exit. But the selection will jump down, and I end up clicking "Remove from Favorites" instead unless I hold my click and move with the jump down.

Any solution to this other than docking on the left side or disabling auto-hide?

Comment: This should probably be reported as a bug. I doubt this is programmed/intended behavior. Bug reporting is essential so that developers can gather enough information about bugs so that they can be fixed. Developers do not use Ask Ubuntu to fix bugs so it is important they are filed through the appropriate channels. For help filing a bug report see: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121)

Comment: This has been reported to Launchpad as a bug #1975724: [Dock right-click menu jumps on autohide](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1975724)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue so as suggested I have reported it as a bug on Launchpad
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1975724